# Simple PHP Authentication Explanation

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I dont really have a clue what I'm doing here. I've got this code but can't get it to work for PHP authentication. Please Help.

```
//Authorise

<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", "0");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "3600");
session_start();
$var = $_SESSION["authenticated"];
if(strcmp($var,'yes') !== 0){
        header('Location: C:\xampp\htdocs\Edge\Authorise.php');
}
?>
```

Login Page

```
<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", "0");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "3600");
session_start();
include('Authorise.php');
echo "<center><h2>This site requires authentication.</h2>";
echo "<br><hr>";
if(isset($_POST['sig_response'])){
        $resp = Duo::verifyResponse(get_cfg_var('duo_ikey'), get_cfg_var('duo_skey'), get_cfg_var('duo_akey'), $_POST['sig_response']);
        if($resp != NULL){
                header('Location: http://localhost:99/edge');
        }
}
else if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
        if($_POST['user'] == get_cfg_var('duo_user') && $_POST['pass'] == get_cfg_var('duo_pass')) {
                $sig_request = Duo::signRequest(get_cfg_var('duo_ikey'), get_cfg_var('duo_skey'), get_cfg_var('duo_akey'), $_POST['user']);
?>
                <script src="Duo-Web-v1.bundled.min.js"></script>
                <input type="hidden" id="duo_host" value="<?php echo get_cfg_var('duo_host') ; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="duo_sig_request" value="<?php $_SESSION["authenticated"] = "yes"; echo $sig_request; ?>">
                <script src="Duo-Init.js"></script>
                <iframe id="duo_iframe" width="620" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="background: transparent;"></iframe>
<?php
        }
}
else {
        echo "<form action='duo.php' method='post'>";
        echo "Username: <input type='text' name='user' /> <br />";
        echo "Password: <input type='password' name='pass' /> <br />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />";
        echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

I got this code from elsewhere. Please can someone explain in more detail to me.
Thanks.

Comment: If you take some time to "get a clue", things will become clearer for you. At this stage you don't even know what the issue is, so that makes in even harder to help.

Answer (score 1):

The request is not very clear, are you trying to learn what the code means? What certain functions mean? Or are you trying to get a fix?

Judging from what you wrote I will assume that you seek an explanation for the code:

**ini_set** changes the php configuration for the run time of the script, means it changes the configuration on the global level of the script.

**session_start** basically starts a session, or continues a current session, it is used for instance when dealing with sessions for login systems, to assign session variables afterwards (e.g $_SESSION["authenticated"])

**strcmp** returns FALSE if equal.

**NOTE:** !== should be changed to !=

You basically declared a condition that if $var is NOT equal to 'yes' then it would redirect to authorize.php via the header function.

You need to read more about the POST and GET methods, as there is a lot to explain and if you do not really know what you are doing, then it is best to read through, considering you are passing information through a form and using the post methods. There is a lot of information out there about these, including pros and cons, security details, it is best to get to know the language a little before dealing with these as well.

Best of luck!